# Shell script (.sh file) not working in crontab but it's working alone

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

> 30 11 * * * /home/ubuntu/Projects/scripts/Sample.sh

and the `syslog` file includes:

> Jun 28 11:30:01 ip-10-98-125-10 CRON[4225]: (tomcat7) CMD
>   (/home/ubuntu/Projects/scripts/Sample.sh)

Please help me; I have been stuck on it!

Comment: Have you looked at any of the questions about "It works at the command line but not in cron" on SO?  There are lots.  The problem almost always boils down to a difference in 'environment'.  Either key environment variables aren't set, or the script is run by `sh` instead of `bash` and the script uses features that aren't supported by `sh`, or it tries to do interactive I/O from standard input and gets into a tizzy when it is given `/dev/null` as standard input, or similarly with output, or …  The list is actually limited, and it is usually one of those.  Without a lot more info, we can't help.

Comment: You should also clarify how you know it is not working in crontab.  Have you run it with `bash -x /home/ubuntu/Projects/scripts/Sample.sh >/tmp/sample.log 2>&1` in the `crontab` entry, for example?  Have you added `env` to the start of the script.  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we need to specify the shell command to run the script.

`30 11 * * * sh /home/ubuntu/Projects/scripts/Sample.sh`

It is obvious that you can not even run `/home/ubuntu/Projects/scripts/Sample.sh` in your interactive shell line. 
Because we need to run either `./home/ubuntu/Projects/scripts/Sample.sh` (only if Smaple.sh is executable) or `sh /home/ubuntu/Projects/scripts/Sample.sh`

So don't forget `sh` or `bash`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LukePeterson Right, here we need to specify the shell command to run the script.